# Solve the first order nonhomogeneous PDE with I.C.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, transport-equation

I am instructed to solve the following:
$$\frac{\partial U(x,t)}{\partial t}+c\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}=2(x-ct)$$
$$u(x,0)=f(x)$$

I said $\frac{dx}{dt}=C \implies x=ct+x_0$ and $\frac{dU}{dt}=g(t)=2(x-ct)$. then $U(x,t)=2xt-ct^2+c_2.$ Using $U(x,0)=f(x)=2x(0)-c(0)+c_2$, then $f(x)=c_2$. $$U(x,t)=2xt-ct^2+f(x).$$
Then for some reason, I feel that I must sub in $x-ct$ in $f(x)$, and I have $u(x,t)=2xt-ct^2+f(x-ct)$. $U(x,0)=f(x)$ confirming the initial condition. $$U_t = 2x-2ct+f'(x-ct)(-c)$$ and $$U_x = 2t+f'(x-ct).$$ $$U_t+cU_x=2x-2ct-cf'(x-ct)+2ct+cf'(x-ct)$$ $$=2x,$$ not $2(x-ct)$ as required.  I have puzzled over this problem many times.  Can anyone help?

Comment: You can just use that $u = u_{h} + u_{p}$ where $u_{h}$ solves the homogeneous problem $u_{t} + c u_{x} = 0$ and $u_{p}$ the inhomogeneous problem $u_{t} + c u_{x} = g(x, t)$. The homogeneous solution is $u_{h} = h(x - ct)$ for some arbitrary differentiable function $h$. The inhomogeneous term $g(x, t) = 2 (x - ct)$ is an uncoupled, first degree polynomial in $x$ and $t$. So you can guess that $u_{p} = A x^{2} + B t^{2}$, substitute this result into the PDE and determine the values of $(A, B)$ (which I find to be $c^{-1}$ and $-c$, respectively).

Comment: Oh yes, that does sound familiar.  I will look back to those notes.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot factor $2$ between steps $\frac{dU}{dt}=2(x-ct)$ and $U(x,t)=2xt-2ct^2+c_2(x)$. that makes the problem till the end. the final solution would be :
$$
U(x,t)=2xt-2ct^2 + f(x-ct) = 2t(x-ct)+f(x-ct)
$$
you can see this satisfy the PDE. 
But it seems your method has some problems (for example you don't know how correctly add $f(x-ct)$) so here's a more detailed solution:

---

This is non-homogeneous first order wave equation, you can solve this similar to D'Alembert solution. 
$$
\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
\xi =x-ct \\
\eta=x +ct
\end{array}\right.
\longrightarrow
\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
\frac{\partial U}{\partial t} =-c \frac{\partial U}{\partial \xi} + c\frac{\partial U}{\partial \eta} \\
\frac{\partial U}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial U}{\partial \xi} + \frac{\partial U}{\partial \eta}
\end{array}\right.
$$
put these back into equation and you get :
$$
2c \frac{\partial U}{\partial \eta} = 2(x-ct) = 2\xi \rightarrow \\
\frac{\partial U}{\partial \eta}= \frac{\xi}{c}
$$
you can easily integrate this :
$$
U(\xi,\eta) = \frac{1}{c}\xi \eta + g(\xi) \\
\Longrightarrow U(x,t) = \frac{1}{c} (x^2-c^2t^2)+g(x-ct) 
$$
now use initial condition $t=0$ :
$$
U(x,0) = \frac{x^2}{c}+g(x)=f(x) \Rightarrow g(x) = f(x)-\frac{x^2}{c}
$$
if you substitute this result into final $U(x,t)$ ,with a little work you get the final solution:
$$
U(x,t) = 2t(x-ct)+f(x-ct)
$$

Comment: Hello.  Thank you for your assistance. I have questions:

Comment: When I integrate 2(x-ct)=2x-2ct, I obtain $2xt-\frac{2}{2}ct^2 +c_2(x)$  which is $2xt-ct^2 +c_2(x).$ Probably the bigger issue is that I do not understand the application of D'Alembert's formula and so do not understand your solution.  Is there a good explanation online you can direct me to?

Comment: yeah you're right. the problem in your solution is somewhere else. in D'Alembert method, we just try to solve the PDE by changing variable from $(x,t)$ to $(\xi,\eta)$ with linear transformation $\xi = a_1 x +a_2 t$ and $\eta=b_1 x+b_2 t$. in this case you can see the choice similar to D'Alembert method for second order wave equation is a good choice. see for example [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/dAlembertsSolution.html) , [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_formula) and [here](https://www.iist.ac.in/sites/default/files/people/IN08026/dAlembert.pdf)